# How to tell if UIViewController's view is visible or not?

Tags: ios

I have a `tabBar` application, with many `views`. Is there a way to know if a particular `UIViewController` is currently visible from within the `UIViewController`? (looking for a `property`)

Answer (score 0):

```
var onScreen: Bool = false

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
    onScreen = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated: animated)
    onScreen = false
}
```

Then you can access your `viewControllerInstance.onScreen` property.